# mac/ios setting up webrtc from the command line and creating a .bash_profile

Tags: ios, macos, shell, webrtc, bash

I am trying to implement webrtc in a native ios app. I am following this tutorial

http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/

The tutorial starts from using the command line and creating a file `.bash_profile`

Step 2 states

2) Download the Chromium depot tools

Switch into your working directory and grab the Chromium depot_tools repository with git:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
```

These are a bunch of tools used during the build process, and they will need to be in your path so you will need to modify your .bash_profile (or other shell file) and modify the PATH line like so:

```
export PATH=/a_bunch_of_stuff:/working_directory/depot_tools:$PATH
```

I am a little confused as what to put into the .bash_profile, what goes inside of `/a_bunch_of_stuff:/`, and is there anything else I should be adding to this .bash_profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just adding one more location to the $PATH. /a_bunch_of_stuff:/ just means all the stuff that is already in your $PATH. The one new location you are adding is the location of your depot_tools.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.